# How to skip real call when doing unit test for mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop

I am writing the unit test for the map reduce program, during the setup() in reduce, it has some context and configuration and htable operations, like this:

```
protected void setup(Context context) {
  try {
    Configuration c = context.getConfiguration();
    table =
        new HTable(c,"TableName");
    table.setAutoFlushTo(false);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.printly(e.toString());
  }
}
```

I've tried to use MRUnit, PowerMock(with Mockito) to mock the conext and configuration, but it seems  not work.

unit test code:

```
Reduce.Context c = reducedriver.getContext();
Configuration confReduce = reducedriver.getConfiguration();

confReduce.setStrings("io.serializations",
    confReduce.get("io.serializations"),
    MutationSerialization.class.getName(),
    ResultSerialization.class.getName(),
    KeyValueSerialization.class.getName());

when(c.getConfiguration()).thenReturn(confReduce);
```

When I run the Unit Test, the context.getConfiguration() seems still try to connect the real hadoop environment and generates lots of zookeeper and connections errors.

How can I fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: `context.getConfiguration()` doesn't connect to anything, your `HTable` connects to ZK, so you need to mock this instead of the config.

Comment: Sorry I modified the code, if I set the the configuration variable c to null, it seems the program will go into deeper.